# IOS/xcode: move core data from app delegate to model class

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

IOS newb struggling with core data.  The Xcode sample project puts core data in app delegate.  Then in the app delegate.m file, within the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method it includes a call to the core data files: `controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;` which fires up the managedobjectcontext in the main controller.

I have read, however, that the app delegate file is not really where you should put the core data stuff but rather you should put it in a model file and call it as a singleton.

My problem is if you move it out of the app delegate file into a file with no `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, how do you make sure the managed object context is available where you need it i.e. in other view controllers?  In other words if all the core data stuff is in the model file, what is the correct syntax to invoke it from a controller file or alternatively makes it available to controller files from model file.

This problem has been driving me crazy for two weeks so would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this example: http://www.objc.io/issue-10/networked-core-data-application.html

There is link to the source code on github, it shows one way of moving coreData code from AppDelegate to a separate model class PersistentStack. In the example, AppDelegate still maintains a reference to the managed object context indirectly through the PersistentStack instance.

There are many other ways to separate coredata code to a separate class depending on the need for modularity.

Comment: I have looked at the tutorial and no doubt it will work similar to other tutorials I have tried but am trying to understand the general principle.  Can you suggest code to make the managed object context etc available to the view controllers.  Do I put the code in the model class or view did load or similar life cycle method in view controller?  In the app delegate version the code is in the app delegate applicationdidfinishlaunching i.e. the same file as the core data stack but if you put it in a model file that subclasses nsobject, there are no lifecycle methods.  HELP!!!

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your concern.  There is no real need to move obtaining managedObjectContext from the AppDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching to individual Model Objects.  I have not seen this being done.  I have seen the actual code for creating a managedObjectContext to another class like the example above.  Typically you only use one managedObjectContext for the full app, set it up in the AppDelegate and pass it to other viewControllers by setting a property on the viewController with the managedObjectContext. You can override the init method of a model object if you really need to

Comment: Is this the code in applicationDidFinishLaunching:  UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    IDTVC *controller = (IDTVC *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    last line is throwing error though  I included model.

Comment: Yes that is the code that is assigning the managedObjectContext to the ViewController.  Can you tell what the error is?